# DialogBoxParam() method is not invoking GUI in IE 9 or above

Tags: c++, dialog

I am VC and VC++ developer. I use VS2008.I have developed an API for capturing the fingerprint through a biometric scanner, in VC. After capturing the fingerprint, I need to display the fingerprint image to the user. So I used DialogBoxParam()method to create a GUI. I have 3 modules. First is the Core DLL, Second is the Windows Service and the Third is Scanner DLL. For capturing the fingerprint, I used to give request from core DLL to the service the will contact the Scanner and revert us back. After the response from the service I call DialogBoxParam() method to show the fingerprint GUI. I have used GetForegroundWindow() to bring the GUI to the front of the browser. In Windows 7, IE 9 or above, the DialogBoxParam() method gets failed. If I avoid GetForegroundWindow(), DialogBoxParam() method got succeeded. I cannot find the solution for this problem. Please help me in this. Below is the code to create the GUI.

*

> DialogBoxParam(GetInstance(),MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_FEATURE_DIALOG),GetForegroundWindow(),(DLGPROC)WndProc,
>   NULL);

*

Answer (score 0):

[DialogBoxParam return -1 and GetLastError return 0 in ActiveX Control](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c9a0ea1c-1c31-4469-94b3-db1f8e6cd7b2/dialogboxparam-return-1-and-getlasterror-return-0-in-activex-control?forum=ieextensiondevelopment)